# Writing image into pdf file in java without saving it

Tags: java, itext

I am generating QR image, and then I save it in PDF file. I am using the following code:

```
BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new BarcodeQRCode("This is a test QR code!", 1, 1, null);
Image image = qrcode.createAwtImage(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
BufferedImage buffImg = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getWidth(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);    
File qrImageFile = new File(qrImageFilePath);
ImageIO.write(buffImg, "png", qrImageFile);
```

Because my PDF file is based on HTML string, so I put the QR image file path in the string (besides other texts and images), and then write the whole string in the PDF.

My question: Can I do the same process without saving the Image on my computer? And if yes, how I can include it in the string?
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what the question is about, but do you consider using other `ImageIO#write` signatures, with `OutputStream` (which does not have to be a `File`)?

Comment: You can obtain a hex array string from your image, and put that entire string into the html file you have. In that way, you don't write the image to a file, but keep it in memory and the pdf html. Bascially you need to get a image to base 64 binary converter in java. See https://codebeautify.org/image-to-base64-converter as an example how to embed a binary string into html using <img> tag

Comment: Hi HarryQ,
I suggest to add your comment as an answer because that's I wanted exactly. However, the image is displayed properly when I save it in html file. But, it isn't displayed in the PDF. Do you have any hint?

Comment: you can add this image directly to document with itext api itself. No need to convert to BufferedImage. if you are encoding as Harry said then you need to decode it to display in pdf